# Disable reuse of ServletRequest instance

Tags: java, webserver, jetty

Is it possible to disable the reuse of the ServletRequest instance for each request? It looks like the instance is reused multiple times (maybe bound per TCP session?)

Comment: Why do you think "looks like" it's reused?

Comment: Store the instance somewhere on a request, If oldReq = req 'true

Answer (score 1):

What you can see in the spec :

```
3.13 Lifetime of the Request Object
Each request object is valid only within the scope of a servlet’s service method, or
within the scope of a filter’s doFilter method, unless the asynchronous processing
is enabled for the component and the startAsync method is invoked on the request
object. In the case where asynchronous processing occurs, the request object remains
valid until complete is invoked on the AsyncContext. Containers commonly recycle
request objects in order to avoid the performance overhead of request object
creation. The developer must be aware that maintaining references to request objects
for which startAsync has not been called outside the scope described above is not
recommended as it may have indeterminate results.
In case of upgrade, the above is still true
```

> Containers commonly recycle
> request objects in order to avoid the performance overhead of request object
> creation

It is container-specific.

In this case it is specific to Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty recycles the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` object between requests.

This is normal, is within the definition of the Servlet Spec, and many containers do this.

Be careful of your usage of the HttpServletRequest / ServletRequest / Request object outside of the dispatch from the container.

If you are using it from an AsyncContext you should only use it when you are called by the container, not any other point or from any other thread (unless you are 100% certain you are handling the threading properly, and are ready to handle one of the thousands of corner cases with AsyncContext from a non-container thread)